# How do I send email from C# without revealing my password?

Tags: c#, email, credentials

I found a great way to send email in C#, except for one problem, I have to show my password. If anyone were to disassemble my program, or if I decided to make it open source (which I probably will) they would get the username and password for my gmail account. Is there any way to get around this?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress("Contact@pandorafreed.com");
mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
mail.Subject = "Pandora Free-D Message";
mail.Body = "Name: " + C.NameBox.Text + "\n" + "Email: " + C.emailBox.Text + "\n" + C.Message.Text;

SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

+++++EDIT+++++

hmmm... would localhost work? Anyone know?

Comment: Create a dummy credentials for now and ask the users of your open source software to replace with this dummy one or their own domain id and credentials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not if your mail server requires authentication.  The program will need to know the password to send mail, and if this program is operating on a computer you don't trust then you can assume the password will be quickly compromised.

You should consider an alternate method, like submitting the mail via a web service or HTTP call to a server under your control, where you can validate the message and then send it to the mail server.

Comment: +1, for clearly indicating that the password will be quickly compromised if run on untrusted computer.

Comment: Exactly why I was asking. I just wanted to know if there was any other methods, as I do not have any sort of email server, or website for it yet.... Hopefully in the future I will, but as for now, I guess I will leave this feature disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could create web-service, which will send e-mail to mail-server.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have others using your account to send e-mail? Let the user use his/her own mailserver and authentication. Let the user enter those values when installing your program and store it in a configuration file.